# Finding matches in a Python multi-dimensional list

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

i'm going nuts here with this and i have a deadline. So i have this multi-d list in python:

```
list_a = [[['a', 'b'],['c', 'd'], ['e', 'CB'], ['g', 'h'], ['a', 'j', 'k']]]
```

Notice, that the whole thing is in 2 brackets.
I need to compare elements like this: a to c, a to d, b to c, b to d, a to e, a to CB...until the first list has compared all it's items with all the items in the other lists, then it moves on to the second list and starts comparing its items to the rest of the lists and so on till the end. I don't want it to compare its own items to its own list.
Here's some code:

```
for i in range(0, len(list_a)):
  for j in range(0, len(list_a)):
    for o in range (0, len(list_a[i])):
        for t in range(1, len(list_a[j])):
            try:
                for x in range(0, len(list_a[i][o])):
                    for y in range(0, len(list_a[j][t])):
                        print list_a[i][o][x], "i=",i, "o=",o, "x=",x
                        print list_a[j][t][y], "j=",j, "t=",t, "y=",y
            except IndexError:
                print ""
```

This one fails cause it compares its own items to its own items. Surely there's a better way to do this rather than putting a lot of forloops inside each other.

And also, i need it to signal me, when it encounters CB. This would be easy if it looped right. Oh, and that "try" over there can be removed i guess. I'm sure this is easy as pie, but i just can't figure it out right now.

Comment: I don't see anything that could be described as comparing. What are you trying to achieve? Also, though you noted the double-nesting of the lists, you didn't explain why this the case.

Comment: Well the comparing part would be to add an if statement somewhere there, that's easy. Right now i'm just printing them all out to see what elements are currently selected.

Comment: Rmitteleitav The only arrays in Python are these ones: (http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#array.array) What you call arrays are in fact lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use itertools to get all pairs from a list and then find all products of them:

```
import itertools
for l1, l2 in itertools.combinations(list_a[0], 2):
    for e1, e2 in itertools.product(l1, l2):
        print e1, e2
```

prints:

```
a c
a d
b c
b d
a e
a CB
b e
b CB
a g
a h
b g
b h
a a
a j
a k
b a
b j
b k
c e
c CB
d e
d CB
c g
c h
d g
d h
c a
c j
c k
d a
d j
d k
e g
e h
CB g
CB h
e a
e j
e k
CB a
CB j
CB k
g a
g j
g k
h a
h j
h k
```

Comment: This one did it for me. I had a clue it had to be done with iterator. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
for o in range (0, len(list_a[i])):
     for t in range(1, len(list_a[j])):
```

The `range(1,...)` for **t** is right when **o** is 0. But when **o** is 1,2,3... then **t** must be in `range(o+1,...):` but only if `i==j`

I think there's only one element [['a', 'b'],...['a', 'j', 'k']] in your exemple to limit the time of execution and display, and I suppose there's in fact other elements. So I tested with a second list as element, assuming what kinds of comparing you'd want to do. So, I observed some problems of indexes  and you'll see the solutions adopted in the following code.

I also changed the display to allow easier analyse  of the process. Note the "trick" consisting in the progressive appending in a list **ecr** and displaying the content of this list at the end. Hence, the display is instantaneous instead of a long line after line display.

```
list_a = [[['a', 'b'],['c', 'd'], ['e', 'CB'], ['g', 'h'], ['a', 'j', 'k']],
          [['l', 'm'],['b', 'n'], ['q', 'r'], ['CB', 'c', 'n']]]


ecr = []
for i in xrange(0, len(list_a)):
    for j in xrange(i, len(list_a)):
        ecr.append('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX i,j='+str(i)+','+str(j))
        for o in xrange (0, len(list_a[i])-(1 if i==j else 0)):
            ecr.append('================= o='+str(o)+'  < '+str(len(list_a[i])-(1 if i==j else 0)))
            for t in xrange(o+1 if i==j else 0, len(list_a[j])):
                ecr.append('------------- o,t='+str(o)+','+str(t))
                try:
                    for x in xrange(0, len(list_a[i][o])):
                        ecr.append('~~~~~~~ x='+str(x))
                        for y in xrange(0, len(list_a[j][t])):
                            ecr.append("i,j="+str(i)+ ","+str(j)+'\n'+\
                                       list_a[i][o][x]+ "  o="+str(o)+ "  x="+str(x)+'\n'+\
                                       list_a[j][t][y]+ "  t="+str(t)+ "  y="+str(y)+'\n'+\
                                         ' ')
                except IndexError:
                    ecr.append( "FAIL")


print '\n'.join(ecr)
```

Does this code correspond to your aim ?

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> list_a = [[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'CB'], ['g', 'h'], ['a', 'j', 'k']]]

>>> k = list_a[0]

>>> c = [(a,b) for b in k for a in k if a!=b] # cartesian excluding self==self

>>> u = [(d,b) for a,b in c for d in a] # unique key, list of values

>>> f = [(a,d) for a,b in u for d in b] # final results (key,value)

>>> print "\n".join(sorted(["%s %s" % x for x in f]))
CB a
CB a
CB b
CB c
CB d
CB g
CB h
CB j
CB k
a CB
a CB
a a
a a
a b
a c
a c
a d
a d
a e
a e
a g
a g
a h
a h
a j
a k
b CB
b a
b c
b d
b e
b g
b h
b j
b k
c CB
c a
c a
c b
c e
c g
c h
c j
c k
d CB
d a
d a
d b
d e
d g
d h
d j
d k
e a
e a
e b
e c
e d
e g
e h
e j
e k
g CB
g a
g a
g b
g c
g d
g e
g j
g k
h CB
h a
h a
h b
h c
h d
h e
h j
h k
j CB
j a
j b
j c
j d
j e
j g
j h
k CB
k a
k b
k c
k d
k e
k g
k h
```